# Word list sequence puzzle

Tags: word-sequence

I found this list of words by a Scot Morris from an old Omni magazine and I can't find the solution.
What is the logic of these words (one for each letter of the alphabet) and (the order is important):

A) schwa

B) splat

C) three

D) grist

E) chore

F) flour

G) sceau

H) filch

I) rinse

J) games

K) canoe

L) reach

M) moire

N) beaux

O) queue

P) angst

Q) intro

R) aster

S) achoo

T) exist

U) awake

V) about

W) adieu

X) eight

Y) outdo

Z) oiled

Comment: Hi Peter are they looking for a word at the end?

Comment: Are the order of these words imortant or are We supposed to just work out a common theme throughout?

Comment: Yes, the order is important, and that is the complete list. What they are looking for is to explain the sequence 1/A=schwa, 2/B=splat, 3/C=three (that's a bit of a red herring I think) etc.

Comment: You really should edit that in...

Comment: Gaargh this ones a toughie!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One interesting thing is that

> If you replace the consonants by 0 and the vowels by 1, you get the binary representation of the numbers 1 to 26 in order.

So perhaps that is the logic to the sequence

A suggestion for the next word in the list

> audio

Comment: I knew you were going to solve this!!!

Comment: That's it! Thanks @hexomino.And thanks Prince Deepthinker for your input.